# MacBook Air crashes regularly

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, crash

After purchasing my MacBook Air (MBA) in April 2013, the MBA crashes on a regular basis (1-2 times per week).  All crashes occur after I wake up the MBA from a Sleep shutdown.  I am brought to the initial log in and I am then advised that the MBA is recovering from an unplanned shutdown and the recovery process starts.  Various software updates and a weekend with the local Apple Store technical team (complete OS re-install) have not resolved anything.

FYI, the current OS X = 10.9.1

Has anyone had a similar experience?  Thoughts? Solutions?  Thank you.